# Figure out If a session object field has been accessed

Tags: java

I have a java object, say `House`, which gets stored in session and gets retrieved by a number of methods. This `House` object has a String field called `streetAddress`.
Say `method1` is a method that retrieves this object from the session and that possibly **accesses** the `streetAddress` field.

By **accesses** I mean even a simple read of this field like `house.getStreetAddress() != null`.

I'm now in `method2`, I retrieve the `House` object from session and I would like to know if the `streetAddress` field has ever been accessed.
This field is private, so the only ways to interact with it outside the class are the getter and setter methods.
Is it possible to know if either one of these two methods has ever been called during this session?

I've looked into java reflection but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly *why* we write getters and setters rather than directly accessing fields. Your getter can take logs internally, and it doesn't affect users of your API. Consider

```
public class House {
  private String streetAddress;
  private boolean streetAddressAccessed;

  public House(String streetAddress) {
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    this.streetAddressAccessed = false;
  }

  public String getStreetAddress() {
    // Somebody called this function; make a note!
    streetAddressAccessed = true;
    return streetAddress;
  }

  public boolean wasStreetAddressAccessed() {
    return streetAddressAccessed;
  }

}
```

Comment: yeah no thank you, that's a good way but the example I made is a bit different than my actual situation. Imagine I have an object containing 100 booleans... and I want to know if one of these has been accessed... I would have to double the number of booleans in the class... I was looking for a smarter way to do it

Comment: A hundred boolean member fields with getters? no offense, but that design doesn't sound smart at all. Why no `java.util.BitSet` ?

Answer (score 0):

You either have to write a proxy by which you access the `House` object that counts the method calls and provides them somehow, or you prepare the implementation of `House` itself to record calls to it's methods.

Another possibility would be the use of a so called "profiler" that measures the time that is spent in called methods. This is more something for the occasional use, e.g. when you are searching for performance bottlenecks.

You could use VisualVM that contains a very simple profiler that can connect to an already running JVM - https://visualvm.github.io/